# Manually simulating Poisson Process in R

Tags: r, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

The following problem tells us to generate a Poisson process step by step from $\rho$ (inter-arrival time), and $\tau$ (arrival time).

> One of the theoretical results presented in the lectures gives the
>   following direct method for simulating Poisson process:
>
> • Let $τ_0 = 0$.
>   • Generate i.i.d. exponential random variables $ρ_1, ρ_2, . . ..$
>   • Let $τ_n = ρ_1 + . . . + ρ_n$ for $n = 1, 2, . . . .$
>   • For each $k = 0, 1, . . .,$ let
>   $N_t = k$ for $τ_k ≤ t < τ_{k+1}$.
>
> 1. Using this method, generate a realization of a Poisson process $(N_t)_t$ with $λ = 0.5$ on the interval $[0, 20]$.
> 2. Generate $10000$ realizations of a Poisson process $(N_t)_t$ with $λ = 0.5$ and use your results to estimate $E(N_t)$ and $Var(N_t)$. Compare the estimates
>      with the theoretical values.

**My attempted solution:**

First, I have generated the values of $\rho$ using `rexp()` function in R.

```
rhos <-function(lambda, max1)
{
    vec <- vector()

    for (i in 1:max1) 
    {
        vec[i] <- rexp(0.5)
    }

    return (vec)
}
```

then, I created $\tau$s by progressive summing of $\rho$s.

```
taos <- function(lambda, max)
{
    rho_vec <- rhos(lambda, max)
    #print(rho_vec)

    vec <- vector()
    vec[1] <- 0
    sum <- 0
    for(i in 2:max)
    {
        sum <- sum + rho_vec[i]
        vec[i] <- sum
    }

    return (vec)
}
```

The following function is for finding the value of $N_t = k$ when the value of $k$ is given. Say, it is $7$, etc.

```
Ntk <- function(lambda, max, k)
{
    tao_vec <- taos(lambda, max)
    val <- max(tao_vec[tao_vec < k])
}

y <- taos(0.5, 20)
x <- seq(0, 20-1, by=1)

plot(x,y, type="s")
```

**Output:**

[image]

As you can see, the plot of the Poisson process is blank rather than a staircase.

If I change `rexp` to `exp`, I get the following output:

[image]

.. which is a staircase function but all steps are equal.

**Why is my source code not producing the expected output?**

Also, I am not sure about my `Ntk()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code already fails within the first function as `rexp(0.5)` does not generate a realization of an exponential random variable. In fact, the first argument of `rexp()` is the number of realizations you want to generate (`n`) followed by the parameter $\lambda$ (`rate`) as the second argument. So there is no need to define the function `rhos()` in the first place. In general, your code is quite cumbersome and redundant.

You may simply generate the arrival times as follows

`cumsum(rexp(n, lambda))`.

or alternatively using the inversion method

`cumsum(-log(runif(n))/lambda)`

for some specified `n` and `lambda`.

Comment: *You may simply generate the arrival times as follows*- I must to go step by step from inter-arrival-time to arrival-time. This has to be implemented manually. So, I think, `cumsum` is not allowed here.

Comment: No one prevents you from doing it with a loop as you did. However, note in this case that your function ```taos()``` is incorrect as the first (inter-)arrival time $\tau_1$ is not contained in your vector.